# Access violation in IActiveScript.AddNamedItem Delphi 64 bit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I'm in the process of trying to migrate apps to 64 bit and have hit a bit of a problem with active scripts. Theres not a lot of information out there about this but I managed to track down the fact that there is a 64 bit version of the IActiveScriptParse interface and so have modified the GUID defs to reflect this as below

```
  SCATID_ActiveScript = '{F0B7A1A1-9847-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  SCATID_ActiveScriptParse = '{F0B7A1A2-9847-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  SID_IActiveScript =        '{BB1A2AE1-A4F9-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  {$IFDEF WIN64}
    SID_IActiveScriptParse =  '{C7EF7658-E1EE-480E-97EA-D52CB4D76D17}';
    SID_IActiveScriptParseProcedureOld ='{21F57128-08C9-4638-BA12-22D15D88DC5C}';
    SID_IActiveScriptParseProcedure = '{C64713B6-E029-4CC5-9200-438B72890B6A}';
    SID_IActiveScriptError =  '{B21FB2A1-5B8F-4963-8C21-21450F84ED7F}';
  {$ELSE}
    SID_IActiveScriptParse =  '{BB1A2AE2-A4F9-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
    SID_IActiveScriptParseProcedureOld ='{1CFF0050-6FDD-11d0-9328-00A0C90DCAA9}';
    SID_IActiveScriptParseProcedure =   '{AA5B6A80-B834-11d0-932F-00A0C90DCAA9}';
    SID_IActiveScriptError =     '{EAE1BA61-A4ED-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  {$ENDIF}
  SID_IActiveScriptSite =        '{DB01A1E3-A42B-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  SID_IActiveScriptSiteWindow =  '{D10F6761-83E9-11cf-8F20-00805F2CD064}';
  SID_IActiveScriptSiteInterruptPoll ='{539698A0-CDCA-11CF-A5EB-00AA0047A063}';
  SID_IBindEventHandler =  '{63CDBCB0-C1B1-11d0-9336-00A0C90DCAA9}';
  SID_IActiveScriptStats = '{B8DA6310-E19B-11d0-933C-00A0C90DCAA9}';
```

This has fixed most of the problems, but I am left with a nagging access violation error when I try to add my apps COM object to the script object using IActiveScript.AddNamedItem eg

```
  ScriptEngine.AddNamedItem(PWideChar(Aname), SCRIPTITEM_GLOBALMEMBERS+SCRIPTITEM_NOCODE+SCRIPTITEM_ISVISIBLE);
```

Other calls to the Scriptengine seem to function OK, only this one produces the AV error and it functions correctly in 32 bit mode.

Is there something I have missed in the script interface updates?

**Update:-** Thanks to Reme Lebeau for providing some insight on this.

So the problem occurs in **IActiveScriptSite.GetItemInfo** which appears to be a callback event that happens when objects are added to the script engine using **IActiveScript.AddNamedItem**. IActiveScriptSite is implemented by the host and for some reason the parameter definitions don't work in 64 bit mode.

Here's the original definition

```
function GetItemInfo(
  pstrName: LPCOLESTR;
  dwReturnMask: DWORD;
  out ppiunkItem: IUnknown;
  out ppti: ITypeInfo): HResult; stdcall;
```

and it needs to be changed to

```
function GetItemInfo(
  pstrName: LPCOLESTR;
  dwReturnMask: DWORD;
  out ppiunkItem: Pointer;
  out ppti: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
```

So with the GUID changes described at the top and the change to the function definition above we are good to go on both 64 and 32 bit.

Comment: Hmm, seems pretty odd that there would be different GUIDs for 32 and 64 bit. That's not normal. It would seem to me therefore that perhaps the 64 bit version of the interface differs from the 32 bit version, hence the decision to use new GUIDs.

Comment: @David - Yes if you look through the registry on a 64 bit machine, there are 2 versions of IactiveScriptParse interface, IactiveScriptParse32 and IactiveScriptParse64. If you try and use the 32 bit interface in a 64 bit app, you will get an "Interface not supported" error on various calls.

Comment: Seems to me that this is a clue. Have you looked at the C++ header for this? Do the interfaces with different GUIDs have different signatures? Have you tried passing the 64 bit type library to the Delphi type library importer and compared the output?

Comment: I haven't managed to find a modern header file. I would have though there would be a type library that the Delphi IDE could import, but nothing shows up on there either. I am assuming its an incompatibility in getting a reference to my apps COM interface when compiled for 64 bit.

Comment: Apparently there are other issues to think about according to this https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/import-64bit-type-libraries-in-delphi/   so the Delphi IDE, as a 32 bit process, can't import 64 bit type libraries.

Comment: I think you can extract the tlb file

Comment: `AddNamedItem()` is not a member of `IActiveScriptParse`. It is a member of `IActiveScript`, which does not have separate 32bit/64bit interfaces. If you define the interfaces in your code, you do not need to import any TypeLibraries. And `IActiveScript` does not have its own CLSID, you use the CLSID of a specific scripting engine (VBScript, JScript, etc) and query it for `IActiveScript`, so make sure you are creating the right COM object for 64bit, and the query for `IActiveScript` is not failing.

Comment: That being said, `AddNamedItem()` is known to have problems with the `SCRIPTITEM_ISSOURCE` and `SCRIPTITEM_GLOBALMEMBERS` flags in Delphi 64bit if you do not declare/handle `GetItemInfo()` correctly, and your code is using the `SCRIPTITEM_GLOBALMEMBERS` flag (BTW, you should be using the `or` operator instead of the `+` operator to combine flags).  See [this past discussion](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/408180973/permalink.art-ng1926q525).  In particular, [this message](http://www.codenewsfast.com/cnf/article/408180973/permalink.art-ng1926q598).

Comment: Yes, that last message fixed it, changing the out parameters in getItemInfo to pointers makes it all work. Is this a problem with the compiler or a delphi include file?  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Also need change System.ObjAuto

```
function GetVariantType(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo): TVarType;
...
    tkClass:
      {$IFDEF WIN32}
      Result := varInteger;
      {$ELSE}
      Result := varInt64;
      {$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delphi Berlin 10.1
Windows 10 64 bit

This solution doesn't work for me:

```pascal
function GetItemInfo(
  pstrName: LPCOLESTR;
  dwReturnMask: DWORD;
  out ppiunkItem: Pointer;
  out ppti: Pointer): HResult; stdcall;
```

I fixed it:

```pascal
PIUnknown = ^IUnknown;
PITypeInfo = ^ITypeInfo;   

function GetItemInfo(
      pstrName: LPCOLESTR;
      dwReturnMask: DWORD;
      ppiunkItem: PIUnknown;
      ppti: PITypeInfo): HResult; stdcall;
```

It works fine.